# onChange in select not working in react js

Tags: reactjs

this is my code, the value of this.state.year is not changing when onChange event is triggered in select. I don't know why. can any one help me out

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './ReportGen.css'

export class ReportGen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      year: 'Academic Year'
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({year: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(this.state);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <select className='drop-down'  placeholder='academic year' name='0' onChange={(e) => this.handleChange}>
            <option value="Academic Year" >Academic Year</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ReportGen
```

when im changing the option and click submit, im still getting academic year as output in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually calling the function:

```
(e) => this.handleChange
```

When you do something like this:

```
onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
```

You don't call the function, but pass the function to the `onSubmit` handler so it will be called when that event happens.

But when you do *this*:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange}
```

You create your own function wrapped around the function you want to call.  The function you created is passed to the `onChange` handler so it will be called when that event happens.  But what does *your function do?  It becomes more clear if we change the syntax a bit:

```
onChange={function (e) {
  this.handleChange;
}}
```

As you can see, your function does nothing.  It just has a single reference to `this.handleChange` but never invokes it.  You can invoke it:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```

Or, even simpler, so what you're *already doing* in the `onSubmit` handler and just pass the function reference directly:

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `e` parameter to your function: `onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}`